# iPhone 6s refuses to boot after screen removal

Tags: iphone, startup, hardware, screen

Have a set of phone repair tools. After removing the iPhone 6s screen (carefully, teasing the ribbons off), and replacing with apple parts, there was an issue turning the phone on even after a hard reset and firmware update. Took the phone to a Genius Bar appointment, and the power test (using a MacBook Air) failed. Three questions:

1. Does removing the screen improperly place a software lock on the iPhone 6s boot?
2. Would this have been caused by the new iOS update?
3. If neither of these, what might cause a screen removal to prevent an iPhone 6s boot?

Comment: A ribbon not seated properly during reassembly?

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced the battery on my old 6S Plus a few times, and each time I had to remove the screen. Nothing broke for me.

If you are lucky, then the ribbon cables did not fully click into place (like little Legos) and it will be a simple fix of unplugging and replugging the connectors. Otherwise it looks like a chance of damage, maybe a connector broke the socket or perhaps a ribbon cable is partially torn.

Does the phone boot while constantly charging? Does it automatically boot when you plug in the cable to a turned off phone? If it works well enough to update the firmware there's a slight chance of a dying battery and needs to be plugged in to get enough power. A power test failure must not be the whole story if you can update it.

Do you see the logo during the update? If yes, then at least the screen cable is ok. You can also disconnect the front camera and try booting with just the video and touch connectors plugged in and see if the camera is broken.

As far as I know, the only lock is when you swap parts and it seems to have started in iPhone 12. If a power test is failing, then your problem is likely hardware.